# ShareActionProvider with AppCompat and ListFragments

Tags: android, fragment, android-appcompat, shareactionprovider

I have recently updated my app to use the AppCompat (v7-22) library in order that I can give my app a Material Design look and feel on all devices. It's all working fine apart from in one activity. I have a BaseActivity with the following code:

```
package com.waldm.proverbica;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResource());
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(hasParentActivity());
        }
    }

    protected abstract boolean hasParentActivity();

    protected abstract int getLayoutResource();
}
```

All my activities extend my BaseActivity.
I have an activity FavouritesActivity whose layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.waldm.proverbica.favourites.FavouritesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_favourites"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and whose code is:

```
package com.waldm.proverbica.favourites;

import com.waldm.proverbica.BaseActivity;
import com.waldm.proverbica.R;

public class FavouritesActivity extends BaseActivity{
    @Override
    protected boolean hasParentActivity() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutResource() {
        return R.layout.activity_favourites;
    }
}
```

and I have a FavouritesFragment class that extends ListFragment.
In the onResume method for the FavouritesFragment, I do the following:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    List<String> favourites = FavouritesIO.readFavourites(getActivity());
    list = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (String favourite : favourites) {
        list.add(ImmutableMap.of(PROVERB_KEY, favourite));
    }

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list, R.layout.list_item_favourites, new String[] { PROVERB_KEY },
            new int[] { R.id.text });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            updateShareIntent();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_item_delete:
                    deleteSelectedItems();
                    mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.favourites, menu);
            shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // Here you can make any necessary updates to the activity when
            // the CAB is removed. By default, selected items are
            // deselected/unchecked.
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Here you can perform updates to the CAB due to
            // an invalidate() request
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

The layout for the fragment is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
              android:textSize="15sp"
              android:text="@string/no_favourites"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem that I'm having is that the ShareActionProvider is always set to null in the onCreateActionMode method, and also that I get two ActionBars/Toolbars being displayed, one for my Fragment, and one for my Activity.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Post your Activity code. You have to extend AppCompatActivity instead of normal Activity class in library 22.1.0. Also layout of FavouritesFragment to show you are not adding Toolbar twice.

Comment: Thanks @Sharj, I have added the requested code.